# Mongoose returns empty object instantiated with req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

Good day!

*Invoice* model has nested *Item* array and I'm instantiating new Item object with *req.body* from **newItem.ejs** but Mongoose is returning empty object even though *req.body* is not empty.

Any advice would be appreciated!

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Invoice = require('./model/invoice');
const Item = require('./model/invoice');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/invoice/:id/newItem', (req, res) => {
    const { id }  = req.params;
    const newItem = new Item(req.body);

    console.log(req.body); // returns {barcode: '666666', vendorRef: 'test', name: 'test', color: 'test' size: '6', cost: '6', quantity: '6'}

    console.log(newItem); // returns { _id: new ObjectId("61d18085424a77e2159b4e38"), items: [] }

    Invoice.findByIdAndUpdate(
        {_id: id},
        {$push: { items: newItem}}).
        then(() => {
            console.log("Item Added")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(err);
        })
    res.redirect(`/search/${id}`);
})
```

The comments above show that the *req.body* is not empty but the object is returning only with id.

**Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    barcode: Number,
    vendorRef: String,
    name: String,
    color: String,
    size: Number,
    cost: Number,
    quantity: Number
})

const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    invoiceNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    invoiceDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    vendor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    store: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    onDelivery: Boolean,
    deliveryDate: Date,
    received: Boolean,
    receivedDate: Date,
    posUpdated: Boolean,
    posUpdatedDate: Date,
    items: [itemSchema]
})

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
const Invoice = mongoose.model('Invoice', invoiceSchema);

module.exports = Item;
module.exports = Invoice;
```

**newItem.ejs**

```
    <form action="/invoice/<%= invoice._id %>/newItem" method="post">

        <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
        <input type="number" id="barcode" name="barcode"> <br>

        <label for="vendorRef">VendorRef</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendorRef" name="vendorRef"> <br>

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> <br>
    
        <label for="color">Color</label>
        <input type="text" id="color" name="color"> <br>

        <label for="size">Size</label>
        <input type="number" id="size" name="size"> <br>

        <label for="cost">Cost</label>
        <input type="number" id="cost" name="cost"> <br>

        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity"> <br>
        
        <button>Add</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have exported the values from the invoice.js file is not correct. You are reassigning the value of `module.exports` to Invoice which is why only that schema is being exported.

Therefore you have imported the wrong model into `Item`. You could either separate the `Item` schema into its own file which would structure things better ie. move the code for the Item schema into `item.js`

```js
// file: models/item.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    barcode: Number,
    vendorRef: String,
    name: String,
    color: String,
    size: Number,
    cost: Number,
    quantity: Number
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

module.exports = {Item, itemSchema};

// file: models/invoice.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {itemSchema} = require("./item.js");
 
const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    invoiceNumber: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    invoiceDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    vendor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    store: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    onDelivery: Boolean,
    deliveryDate: Date,
    received: Boolean,
    receivedDate: Date,
    posUpdated: Boolean,
    posUpdatedDate: Date,
    items: [itemSchema]
})

const Invoice = mongoose.model('Invoice', invoiceSchema);

module.exports = {Invoice, invoiceSchema};

// file: index.js
const { Invoice } = require('./model/invoice');
const { Item } = require('./model/item');
```

OR

You could destructure the schemas from the same file in a single line

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Invoice, Item }= require('./model/invoice'); // This line
// const = require('./model/invoice');// Get rid of this
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

to do this you would also have to change the exports line in `invoice.js` to

```js
module.exports = {Item, Invoice}
```